# is it possible to treat string methods as functions?

Tags: python, function, methods

is it possible to write a wrapper function for methods?

```
>>> lowtide = [ 'oh', 'i', 'do', 'like', 'to', 'be', 'beside', 'the', 'seaside' ]

>>> [ x.capitalize() for x in lowtide ]
['Oh', 'I', 'Do', 'Like', 'To', 'Be', 'Beside', 'The', 'Seaside']

>>> list(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(), lowtide))
['Oh', 'I', 'Do', 'Like', 'To', 'Be', 'Beside', 'The', 'Seaside']


>>> def mef(m):
...     def _mef(m,x):
...         return x.m()
...     return partial(_mef, m)
... 
>>> list(map(mef(capitalize), lowtide))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'capitalize' is not defined
```

Comment: Your `mef` function could be made to work by replacing `x.m` with `getattr(x, m)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can use `str.capitalize` and `unicode.capitalize`, these can fail if you assume a certain type... The safest method is to just use:

```
from operator import methodcaller
capitalize = methodcaller('capitalize')
```

Which guarantees the correct method is used for the object, and also allows duck typing to be done successfully.

**excerpt from a post from me to Google Groups/comp.lang.python 23 Aug 2010**

> Using methodcaller allows you to 'preserve' Python's duck-typing as
>   well as any over-ridden methods in subclasses. In your example, this
>   is probably overkill as you're only dealing with one class
>
> Another (convoluted) example:

```
class mystr(str):
    def lower(self):
        return self.upper()

>>> s = mystr('abc')
>>> s.lower()
'ABC'

>>> lower = methodcaller('lower')
>>> lower(s)
'ABC'

>>> str.lower(s)
'abc'
```

> ^^^ Most likely incorrect
>
> It also adds a further bit of flexibility (which can be emulated with
>   functools.partial admittedly):

```
split_tab = methodcaller('split', '\t')
split_comma = methodcaller('split', ',')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do

```
list(map(str.capitalize, lowtide))
```

In Python 3.x, `str.capitalize()` is a function taking the single argument `self`.

In Python 2.x, `str.capitalize()` is an "unbound method", but behaves similar to a function taking a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could rewrite your `mef` function to get this to work properly.  The benefit here over using `str.capitalize` is that it will work for Unicode strings as well on Python 2.x:

```
def mef(m):
    def _mef(x):
        return getattr(x, m)()
    return _mef

list(map(mef('capitalize'), lowtide))
```

Note that this is essentially the same thing as using `lambda x: x.capitalize()`.